# How to use miniprofiler to help us crush loading speeds?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, azure, mvc-mini-profiler

As a developer and constant user of minipfoler, I use stakoverflow as the benchmark for my .NET sites. That is because the entire stack network is just a blazingly fast.

I know miniprofiler is used on stackexchange. There is a whole developers thing that can be used on stack but can we enable the stats to see how fast it really is?

I might be bit over obsessive here - but I am looking to improve permanences in milliseconds and the only viable benchmark is a large and complex site like stack exchange.

I know it might be a security issue to see live data but I just really want a benchmark (screenshot / guidelines) to see how far I can optimize my .NET MVC web application.

My actual IIS and MVC performance is fantastic and I think I am more concerned about server replies and client side stuff. So can I (and should I) put more effort into smashing down this response time?

This site is hosted in Azure Cloupapp and using Azure DB - I know about 60~180ms is used on connection times that are out of my control.

How can I improve times between Paint, Load and Complete?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that I answer my own question on StackExchange more often now a days. Not sure what that means.  But this in interesting what I found while dealing with other Q&A's (And it answered this question)

> Yes, you should avoid the obvious beginner mistakes of string
>   concatenation, the stuff every programmer learns their first year on
>   the job. But after that, you should be more worried about the
>   maintainability and readability of your code than its performance. And
>   that is perhaps the most tragic thing about letting yourself get
>   sucked into micro-optimization theater -- **it distracts you from your**
>    **real goal: writing better code.**
>
> [Posted by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

There is no real problem in performance or serious delays. Its just an obsession that wont lead to much satisfaction.

The 'dudes' got a point. As long as my code is readable and it runs fast - what the heck more do I want?

PERFECTION! - Waste of time, lol@me!